# Convert set of object's into array item

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have several objects like this:

```
{'id[0]': 2}
{'url[0]': 11}
{'id[1]': 3}
{'url[1]': 14}
```

And I want to get something like this:

```
[{id:2, url:11}, {id:3, url:14}]
```

Also I have lodash in my project. Maybe lodash have some method for this?

Comment: i think we need to parse the keys of objects using regex .

Comment: how you are carrying these several objects

Comment: @Viplock in hand .

Comment: Are you trying to merge every two objects?

Comment: @guest271314 no maybe he is trying to merge using this `[0]` and `[1]`

Comment: @Mahi Did not initially notice that correlation.

Comment: I trying to merge this with regex. Map to objects, then get key by regex, than with this key add item to array. Not so elegant. So maybe lodash have some simple method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for the keys and create a new object if necessary. Then assign the value to the key.

```js
var data = [{ 'id[0]': 2 }, { 'url[0]': 11 }, { 'id[1]': 3 }, { 'url[1]': 14 }],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        var keys = k.match(/^([^\[]+)\[(\d+)\]$/);
        if (keys.length === 3) {
            result[keys[2]] = result[keys[2]] || {};
            result[keys[2]][keys[1]] = a[k];
        }
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an ES6 solution based on [@NinaScholz solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41034240/5157454).

I assume that the objects have only one property each, like the ones presented in the question.

1. Combine the array of objects to one large object using [`Object#assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), and convert to entries with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).
2. Iterate the array using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
3. Extract the original key an value from each entry using [array
   destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
4. Extract the wanted key and index using a regex and array
   destructuring.
5. Then create/update the new object at the index using [object spread](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread).

```js
const data = [{ 'id[0]': 2 }, { 'url[0]': 11 }, { 'id[1]': 3 }, { 'url[1]': 14 }];

// combine to one object, and convert to entries
const result = Object.entries(Object.assign({}, ...data)) 
  // extract the original key and value
  .reduce((r, [k, value]) => {
    
    // extract the key and index while ignoring the full match
    const [, key, index] = k.match(/^([^\[]+)\[(\d+)\]$/);

    // create/update the object at the index
    r[index] = {...(r[index] || {}), [key]: value }; 

    return r;
  }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [{'id[0]': 2},
{'url[0]': 11},
{'id[1]': 3},
{'url[1]': 14}];

var result = [];

arr.forEach(function(e, i, a){
  var index = +Object.keys(e)[0].split('[')[1].split(']')[0];//get the number inside []
  result[index] = result[index] || {}; //if item is undefined make it empty object 
  result[index][Object.keys(e)[0].split('[')[0]] = e[Object.keys(e)[0]];//add item to object
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop, `.filter()`, `RegExp` constructor with parameter  `"\["+i+"\]"` where `i` is current index, `Object.keys()`, `.reduce()`, `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\[\d+\]/`

```js
var obj = [{
  "id[0]": 2
}, {
  "url[0]": 11
}, {
  "id[1]": 3
}, {
  "url[1]": 14
}];

var res = [];
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length / 2; i++) {
  res[i] = obj.filter(function(o) {
             return new RegExp("\[" + i + "\]").test(Object.keys(o))
           })
           .reduce(function(obj, o) {
             var key = Object.keys(o).pop();
             obj[key.replace(/\[\d+\]/, "")] = o[key];
             return obj
           }, {})
}

console.log(res);
```